# Count milestone By Id in Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql

[table milestoneevent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37qo1.jpg)I have three tables file and milestone event. I want to count milestones but by Company.

For example, if I want to count number of last milestone added for the milestone `id=1`,  I do this:

```
select count('id') as st 
from (
  select idfile,
  max(idmilestone) as max_idmilestone 
  from milestoneevent 
  group by idfile) 
d where max_idmilestone =1
```

my problem is how to count them but for each company in table file I have column company. See the picture for more details

[image]

Comment: Can you please make this questio more clearer. Some information is missing. What company in what table file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statement should look like this

```
SELECT d.Comp,count(*),d.max_idmilestone FROM (
        SELECT Comp, max(idmilestone) as max_idmilestone, count(idmilestone) as number FROM milestoneevent
        INNER JOIN file ON file.id = idfile
        GROUP BY idfile, Comp
) d GROUP BY d.max_idmilestone, d.Comp
```

In the subquery it give you the max(idmilestone) for every company but only if one milestone exists for a idfile, than count how many a max_idmilestone is occuring.

**The Result of my test is**

```
+-----------+----------+---+
| Comp      | count(*) |   |
+-----------+----------+---+
| Microsoft |        5 | 1 |
| Oracle    |        1 | 1 |
| Microsoft |        2 | 2 |
| Oracle    |        1 | 2 | 
+-----------+----------+---+
```

**Query for Company or milestoneid

If you want to query for Company or max_idmilestone just do this

```
SELECT d.Comp,count(*),d.max_idmilestone FROM (
        SELECT Comp, max(idmilestone) as max_idmilestone, count(idmilestone) as number FROM milestoneevent
        INNER JOIN file ON file.id = idfile 
        WHERE Comp = "Microsoft"
        GROUP BY idfile, Comp
) d 
WHERE d.max_idmilestone = 1
GROUP BY d.max_idmilestone, d.Comp
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+----------+---+
| Comp      | count(*) |   |
+-----------+----------+---+
| Microsoft |        5 | 1 |
+-----------+----------+---+
```

**For My Test I used the following structure. Skipped some columns which are not necessary for the test**

```
CREATE TABLE `milestoneevent` (
  `id` INT(22) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `idfile` INT(64) NOT NULL,
  `idmilestone` INT(64) NOT NULL,
  `company` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `file` (
  `id` int(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Comp` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Data of the test**

```
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | idfile | idmilestone |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 |      1 |           1 |
|  2 |     10 |           1 |
|  3 |     11 |           1 |
|  4 |     12 |           1 |
|  5 |     13 |           1 |
|  6 |     14 |           1 |
|  7 |     15 |           1 |
|  8 |     16 |           2 |
|  9 |     14 |           2 |
| 10 |     18 |           2 |
+----+--------+-------------+


+----+-----------+
| id | Comp      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Microsoft |
| 10 | Microsoft |
| 11 | Microsoft |
| 12 | Microsoft |
| 13 | Microsoft |
| 14 | Microsoft |
| 15 | Oracle    |
| 16 | Oracle    |
| 18 | Microsoft |
+----+-----------+
```

Comment: and in your query I can't see for exmple company='Microsoft'

Comment: @medfbfrero  Result is all. Number of milestones for Companies which have only the milestone 1. Inlcuded company name if you want a specific company then just use where company = 'Microsoft'

Comment: it return error when I do this 

SELECT file.Comp, count(file.company) as st 
FROM (
  SELECT idfile, Comp, max(idmilestone) as max_idmilestone 
  FROM milestoneevent,file 
  GROUP BY idfile HAVING max_idmilestone = 1 and  Comp = 'Microsoft' 
) d
GROUP BY Comp

Comment: @medfbfrero perhaps make group by d.company but i will evaluate it

Comment: @medfbfrero I tested my Query and it's ok. I added the test to my answer. Which error occurs which the query in my answer?

Comment: Kordi  the problem that company is in other table caled file  You understand   I realy apreciate Your Help

Comment: @medfbfrero ok no problem and how does the structure of the other file look, or how they related together? I just guessing via the field idfile

Comment: look
table file
Id --- company ---date----type-----etc
table milestone
id libelle
table milestoenevent
id idfile idmilestone date
what I want is like this
Company--  lastmilestone we add---   count
microsoft                 2                            140
google                     1                                 18
etc...

Comment: @medfbfrero Now it should work .. see my updated answer.

Comment: it return empty result:
SELECT d.comp, count(d.comp) as st FROM ( SELECT idfile, comp, max(idmilestone) as max_idmilestone FROM milestoneevent INNER JOIN file ON file.id = idfile GROUP BY idfile, comp HAVING max_idmilestone = 1 ) d GROUP BY d.comp 

how can I show u some screen shot

Comment: @medfbfrero Just use http://imgur.com/ would like to see a screenshot of the file table.

Comment: Can I contact You by mail I think its better or with somethink like facebook